# What's a good way to handle post data in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I.e. would you recommend me to use one controller method like this:

```
function save()
{
    if(!is_bool($this->input->post('')))
    {
        $post_data = $this->input->post('');
        $this->mymodel->save($post_data);
    }
    $this->load->view('myview');
}
```

Or would you recommend writing it using two methods?

```
function save()
{
    if(!is_bool($this->input->post('')))
    {
        $post_data = $this->input->post('');
        $this->mymodel->save($post_data);
    }
    redirect('controller/method2')
}
```

The redirect is the crucial difference here. It prohibits resubmissions from update for example.

How do you do it? Is there another better way?

Comment: Although the concept link is already posted in the answers, to save some time, just look into [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should **always** redirect on a successful form post.

Comment: +1000 internet points for you Aren. Everyone should know that one simple rule.

Answer (score 9):

> You should **always** redirect on a successful form post.

Absolutely.  For anyone wondering *why* this is the case, here are a couple of the reasons:

- **Avoid "duplicate submissions"**.  Ever had that when you innocently click refresh or hit the back button and *wham*, everything has resubmitted?
- **Being friendly to bookmarks**.  If your user bookmarks the page, presumably you want them to return where they created it, rather than a blank form (a redirect makes them bookmark the confirmation/landing page.

Further reading:
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 3):

As Aren B said, redirection is a good idea, but what I would change in your code is that validation of the post data should be done with the form validation functionallity. It is not only more reauseable but the code will get shorter.

If you want to handle AJAX requests, you would need to return something else than a via or a redirection.